# what is difference between open and mixed queue

Tags: applications, queueing-theory, network

please consider this image:
[image]

In this picture that I got it from [Here](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-08/ftp/k_32qn.pdf) write said that Network C is Open,B is Mixed and A is Closed.

I want to know why C isn't mixed? `Video Server 1,2,...m` are closed so C is mixed.

`Video Server 1,2,...m` is like `Admin`...

please guide me why C is open and B is mixed

thanks

Comment: consider [Scientific Computing](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look very closely, the arrow are going out... in network C.

$$ \leftarrow \boxed{\cdot} $$

So $C$ is "open", while $B$ has information going in and out.  It is mixed:

$$ \leftarrow \boxed{\cdot}  \leftarrow $$

$A$ is closed since no information is coming in or out:

$$\boxed{\cdot  \leftarrow \cdot}  $$

---

$$ \boxed{ \cdot \to \boxed{\boxed{\cdot}_C \leftarrow \cdot }_B\to \cdot}_A$$

Please look at the exercise on [box algebra](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Arithmetic.htm) by knot-theorist Lou Kaufmann, or this article on the [little 2-cubes operad](http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf) by Jim Stasheff

---

$$
\boxed{\text{Users} \leftrightarrow \boxed{\boxed{\text{Proxy } \leftrightarrow \text{Video Server}}_A \leftrightarrow \text{Admin}}_B}_C
 $$

Here are the definitions from your notes:

- **Open**  model in which jobs departing from one 
  queue arrive at another queue (or possibly the same queue)
- **Closed** Closed queueing network: No external arrivals or departures; Total number of jobs in the system is constant
- **Mixed** Open for some workloads and 
  closed for others ⇒ Two classes of jobs.

Network C is open to external information.  A is closed there nothing going in and out.  B is open to **user** jobs but closed to **admin** jobs.

Comment: Thanks But Why You don't consider Arrow that going in From `User 2` to _C_?

Comment: @Nima this picture is **simplification** the real picture should have more arrows

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.I mean that when you consider arrow from `User 2` to _C_ then _C_ is also mixed because `Video Server`s hava not arrow from In or Out and `Proxy` has out arrow To `Admin` or `User 2` and In arrow from `User 2`.I wish I could decribe mell my mean

Comment: thanks dear @john why you didn't say that `Video server` are closed so _C_ is mixed?

Comment: @Nima `VideoServer` is definitely **not** closed since information is coming *in* and *out*.

Comment: Thanks dear friend but For `Admin` we have this:Arrows coming _in_ and _out_ So why you said that B is mixed.I'm confused for this part

Comment: @Nima B could be mixed or open depending on your point of view.  It's not clear from the diagram.